# Improving Performance of a Regular Expression on a Large String

Tags: c#, regex

I am currently using a regular expression in my code in order to grab a large string from a rich text document. The regular expression finds any embedded images and parses them into a byte array that I can convert into a LinkedResource.  I need to convert an RTF from a RichTextBox in my application into a valid HTML document, and then into a MIME-encoded message that can be automatically sent.

The problem with the regular is expression is that the string section of the image is very large, so I feel like the regular expression is trying to match many possibilities within the entire string when, in reality, I only need to look at the beginning and end of the section. The regular expression below is contained within a larger regular expression as an optional clause, such as `someRegexStringA + "|" + imageRegexString + "|" + "someRegexStringB"`.

What can I do to ensure that there is less checking within large strings so that my application doesn't appear to freeze when parsing large amounts of image data?

```
// The Regex itself
private static string imageRegexString = @"(?<imageCheck>\\pict)"                  // Look for the opening image tag
                                       + @"(?:\\picwgoal(?<widthNumber>[0-9]+))"   // Read the size of the image's width
                                       + @"(?:\\pichgoal(?<heightNumber>[0-9]+))"  // Read the size of the image's height
                                       + @"(?:\\pngblip(\r|\n))"                   // The image is the newline after this portion of the opening tag and information
                                       + @"(?<imageData>(.|\r|\n)+?)"              // Read the bitmap
                                       + @"(?:}+)";                                // Look for closing braces

// The expression is compiled so it doesn't take as much time during runtime
private static Regex myRegularExpression = new Regex(imageRegexString, RegexOptions.Compiled);

// Iterate through each image in the document
foreach(Match image in myRegularExpression.Matches(myDocument))
{
    // Read the image height and width
    int imageWidth = int.Parse(image.Groups["widthNumber"].Value);
    int imageHeight = int.Parse(image.Groups["heightNumber"].Value);

    // Process the image
    ProcessImageData(image.Groups["imageData"].Value);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if RTF is a regular language, but there are libraries made specifically for parsing RTF documents into a DOM tree.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtfdomparser/  It should give you a significant boost in performance.  (Note: I haven't tried this library).  Using the right tool should help, though.  You may try googling "RTF DOM parsing C#" for other resources.

Comment: i think you should discard the use of RegEx, can you parse the rtf document in binary mode?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use external libraries for this due to legal reasons and my employer. Also, I have already looked into doing something similar on my own and though it work, a large amount of effort has gone into the current method of parsing.

Comment: I need to parse the document into an HTML equivalent, so I need to be able to parse the tags of the RTF. Would there be a good way to read the RTF as a binary stream that I could do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I vaguely remember having an InfoPath form with a Rich Text Editor that could be exported to HTML - so you may want to look at that (though we still had to attach the images separately)

As for your pattern: it is pretty straightforward, there is only one suspicious line:

```
(?<imageData>(.|\r|\n)+?)
```

This has several potential problems:

- `+?` is lazy, and **for long strings** causes a lot of backtracking, which may be inefficient.
- `.|\r|\n` also seems pretty inefficient. You can use the [SingleLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) modifier (or [inline `(?s:...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#options)).
  By the way, [`.` already matches `\r`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes).
- `(.|\r|\n)` - This is a **capturing group**, unlike the  `(?:...)` group you use elsewhere. I suspect this is *killing* you - in .Net, each character is saved in a stack as a `Capture`. You don't want that.

I'd suggest this instead, with a [possessive group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#nonbacktracking_subexpression), just to be safe:

```
(?<imageData>(?>[^}]+))
```

Of course, it is also possible the pattern is slow because of the other alternations: `someRegexStringA` or `someRegexStringB`.

Comment: Excellent explanation, I wasn't aware of the SingleLine modifier. Also, this led to several other optimizations that stemmed from my misunderstanding of regular expressions. Thank you!